# What is wrong with my code in python?

Tags: python, bbc-microbit

In my code, its supposed to be a magic 8 ball that is rigged. Pressing A should show "Yes!", pressing B should show "No."
But every time, it shows "Yes!" without any buttons being pressed.

```
from microbit import *
import random

frameq = Image("00000:""00000:""00900:""00000:""00000")
framew = Image("00000:""09990:""09390:""09990:""00000")
framee = Image("99999:""93339:""93339:""93339:""99999")
framer = Image("33333:""33333:""33333:""33333:""33333")
framet = Image("22222:""22222:""22222:""22222:""22222")
framey = Image("11111:""11111:""11111:""11111:""11111")
frames = [frameq, framew, framee, framer, framet, framey]
answers = [
    "It is certain",
    "It is decidedly so",
    "Without a doubt",
    "Yes, definitely",
    "You may rely on it",
    "As I see it, yes",
    "Most likely",
    "Outlook good",
    "Yes",
    "Signs point to yes",
    "Reply hazy try again",
    "Ask again later",
    "Better not tell you now",
    "Cannot predict now",
    "Concentrate and ask again",
    "Don't count on it"
    "My reply is no",
    "My sources say no",
    "Outlook not so good",
    "Very doubtful",
]
apress = False
bpress = False
while True:
    if button_a.is_pressed:
        bpress = False
        apress = True
    elif button_b.is_pressed:
        apress = False
        bpress = True
    display.show("8")
        if accelerometer.was_gesture("shake") and apress is True:
        display.clear()
        display.show(frames, loop=False, delay=250)
        sleep(1000)
        display.show("Yes!")
        apress = False
    elif accelerometer.was_gesture("shake") and bpress is True:
        display.clear()
        display.show(frames, loop=False, delay=250)
        sleep(1000)
        display.show("No.")
        bpress = False
    elif accelerometer.was_gesture("shake"):
        display.clear()
        display.show(frames, loop=False, delay=250)
        sleep(1000)
        display.scroll(random.choice(answers))
```

It shows no error message, it just shows "Yes!" every single time I shake. And by the way, "Yes!" is not in the answers array, only "Yes", and I always see the !.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without any more context, one can only assume what the problem is.
Make sure that `is_pressed` is not a function:

```
if button_a.is_pressed:
    bpress = False
    apress = True
elif button_b.is_pressed:
    apress = False
    bpress = True
```

if `is_pressed` is a function then `button_a.is_pressed` will *always* be `True` hence `apress` will always be `True` hence you will always get `'Yes!'` printed.

Try to change the above code to

```
if button_a.is_pressed():
    bpress = False
    apress = True
elif button_b.is_pressed():
    apress = False
    bpress = True
```

Otherwise, **debug** you program. Add print statements in different execution paths and see what causes each `if` statement to be `True`.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you DeepSpace!
After some touch ups, this is my final code.
I'm sorry I didn't make this clear, but it was a magic 8 ball that could be rigged. by pressing A or B.
Here is the final code:

```
from microbit import *
import random

frameq = Image("00000:""00000:""00900:""00000:""00000")
framew = Image("00000:""09990:""09390:""09990:""00000")
framee = Image("99999:""93339:""93339:""93339:""99999")
framer = Image("33333:""33333:""33333:""33333:""33333")
framet = Image("22222:""22222:""22222:""22222:""22222")
framey = Image("11111:""11111:""11111:""11111:""11111")
frames = [frameq, framew, framee, framer, framet, framey]
answers = [
    "It is certain",
    "It is decidedly so",
    "Without a doubt",
    "Yes, definitely",
    "You may rely on it",
    "As I see it, yes",
    "Most likely",
    "Outlook good",
    "Yes",
    "Signs point to yes",
    "Reply hazy try again",
    "Ask again later",
    "Better not tell you now",
    "Cannot predict now",
    "Concentrate and ask again",
    "Don't count on it"
    "My reply is no",
    "My sources say no",
    "Outlook not so good",
    "Very doubtful",
]
apress = False
bpress = False
while True:
    if button_a.is_pressed():
        bpress = False
        apress = True
    elif button_b.is_pressed():
        apress = False
        bpress = True
    display.show("8")
    if accelerometer.was_gesture("shake"):
        if apress:
            display.clear()
            display.show(frames, loop=False, delay=250)
            sleep(1000)
            display.show("Yes!")
            apress = False
        elif bpress:
            display.clear()
            display.show(frames, loop=False, delay=250)
            sleep(1000)
            display.show("No.")
            bpress = False
        else:
            display.clear()
            display.show(frames, loop=False, delay=250)
            sleep(1000)
            display.scroll(random.choice(answers))
```